# Does no airy disk/pattern mean that a converging beam of light is not at its focal plane?

Tags: optics

From wikipedia: "In optics, the Airy disk (or Airy disc) and Airy pattern are descriptions of the best focused spot of light that a perfect lens with a circular aperture can make, limited by the diffraction of light."

So, is this saying that if I have a camera looking at a converging beam laser, that I am going to see an airy pattern (concentric circles) if and only if the camera is at the focal plane?

Comment: The Wikipedia statement makes no mention of the focal plane of the perfect lens,

Comment: @Farcher "the best focused spot of light" Only happens at the focal plane right

Comment: It depends where the spot of light is relative to the lens.

Comment: @Farcher Not understanding your point

Comment: The Airy disc is formed in the image plane which is not necessarily the focal plane.

Comment: @Farcher But it says it's formed at the focus. "The best focused spot of light" would be at the focus, right?

Comment: I can see that the focal plane / best focused spot wasn't adequately resolved so let me explain this quickly. Focal plane is the plane where a light point infinitely far away will make a sharp image. Any light point at a finite distance will make a sharp image at a different plane, which will be farther away from the lens than the focal plane, as governed by the so-called _thin lens equation_. This is why photographic lenses require a focusing mechanism.